# Extract content with XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have html content that I am storing as an XML document (using HTML Agility Pack). I know some XPath, but I am not able to zero into the exact content I need.

In my example below, I am trying to extract the "src" and "alt" text from the large image. This is my example:

```
<html>
<body>
   ....
   <div id="large_image_display">
      <img class="photo" src="images/KC0763_l.jpg" alt="Circles t-shirt - Navy" />
   </div>
   ....
   <div id="small_image_display">
      <img class="photo" src="images/KC0763_s.jpg" alt="Circles t-shirt - Navy" />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the XPath to get "images/KC0763_l.jpg" and "Circles t-shirt - Navy"? This is how far I got but it is wrong. Mostly pseudo code at this point:

```
\\div[@class='large_image_display']\img[1][@class='photo']@src
\\div[@class='large_image_display']\img[1][@class='photo']@alt
```

Any help in getting this right would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Food question, +1! See my answer for a better, more efficient solution and for a detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath will get you to the src attributes for the img tags:

```
'//html/body/div/img[@class="photo"]/@src'
```

And similarly this will get you to the alt attributes:

```
'//html/body/div/img[@class="photo"]/@alt'
```

From there you can get to the attribute text. If you want to only find the ones that match 'large_image_display' then you would filter it further like this:

```
'//html/body/div[@id="large_image_display"]/img[@class="photo"]/@src'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following XPath expressions**:

```
/html/body/div[@id='large_image_display']/img/@src
```

and

```
/html/body/div[@id='large_image_display']/img/@alt
```

**Always try to avoid using the** `//` **abbreviation**, because it may result in very inefficient evaluation (causes the whole (sub)tree to be scanned).

In this particular case we know that the `html` element is the top element of the document and we can simply select it by `/html` -- not `//html`.

**Your major problem was** that in your expressions you were using `\` and `\\` and there are no such operators in XPath. The correct XPath operators you were trying to use are `/` and the `//` abbreviation.